# There is an error in my app

Tags: java, android, csv

I'm making an app that will show multiple location on google map and I've read it through csv file. I have an error at OnCreate and displarArrayList method.

This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at com.w2s.where2shop.ShowAllMap$CSVFile.displayArrayList(ShowAllMap.java:267)
at com.w2s.where2shop.ShowAllMap.onCreate(ShowAllMap.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

This is onCreate

```
 private InputStream inputStream;
private CSVFile csvFile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_all_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.allmap);
    csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    csvFile.read();
    try {
        csvFile.displayArrayList();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER)
            .setNumUpdates(1);


}
```

And this is where I read my csv file  and inside the class CsvFile I got displayarrayItem method.

```
public class CSVFile {
    InputStream inputStream;
    ArrayList<String[]> addressList;


    public CSVFile(InputStream is) {
        this.inputStream = is;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> read() {
        ArrayList<String[]> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                addressList.add(row);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return addressList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> displayArrayList() throws IOException {
        for (int x = 0; x > this.addressList.size(); x++) {

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ShowAllMap.this);
            List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(addressList.get(x).toString(), 1);

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                Address add = list.get(0);
                double lat = add.getLatitude();
                double lng = add.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                mMap.addMarker(options);


            }
        }
        return addressList;
    }

}
```

Comment: ArrayList<String[]> addressList; you have diclared arraylist but not yet instantiate.

Comment: in `CSVFile.read()` method replace `ArrayList<String[]> addressList = new ArrayList<>();` with `addressList = new ArrayList<>();` your local var hides your field because has the same name and your field in null all the time

Comment: Thanks for the hlp, now it has no error. But when I run the app. There is no marker.

Comment: Please try to make more of an effort with your titles: `There is an error in my app` is not very useful when readers see it in search results or on the front page. Txtspk of `hlp plz` is also discouraged - Stack Overflow is not a chat site.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the global arrayList, but you also created same array list in the read() method, so remove the declaration as well as make sure the arrayList is not null in displayArrayList() method.

```
 public class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;
        ArrayList<String[]> addressList;


        public CSVFile(InputStream is) {
            this.inputStream = is;
        }

        public ArrayList<String[]> read() {
             addressList = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    addressList.add(row);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return addressList;
        }

        public ArrayList<String[]> displayArrayList() throws IOException {
        if(addressList != null){
            for (int x = 0; x > this.addressList.size(); x++) {

                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ShowAllMap.this);
                List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(addressList.get(x).toString(), 1);

                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    Address add = list.get(0);
                    double lat = add.getLatitude();
                    double lng = add.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng);
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                    mMap.addMarker(options);


                }
            }
            }
            return addressList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks , It has no error, but the marker isnt showing

Answer (score 1):

change `for (int x = 0; x > this.addressList.size(); x++)`  to  `for (int x = 0; x < this.addressList.size(); x++)`  in displayArrayList()

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your ArrayList `ArrayList<String[]> addressList = new ArrayList<>();`is local. Outside of read method your ArrayList is not defined thats why you are getting this error.

Sol. Declare your ArrayList in `onCreate` before calling read() and displayArraylist() methods.

this may help you.